# Redirecionar HTTPS para HTTP no Centos

Tags: linux, apache, centos

Tenho um domínio a qual não tenho mais o certificado ssl dele, o domínio está apontando para um servidor Centos 6. Toda vez que alguém tenta acessar ele utilizando **HTTPS** ele vai mostrar no navegador que aquele dominio não é seguro pois não tem um certificado válido ativo.

**Minha dúvida é:** Existe a possíbilidade de eu redirecionar o usuário quando tentar acessar através do **HTTPS** jogar ele para o **HTTP**, sem que tenha que aparecer aquela tela no navegador falando que é inseguro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe sim.

Vá até a pasta onde o seu domino(site) se encontra, exemplo: `/var/www/html/meusite.com.br/`:

vim .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```